# Generically find any items where item property value is equal using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection

I'm trying to implement a generic repository pattern that implements CRUD operations of generic items in an `IEnumerable`. I'm having issue of generically finding an item that may already be in the `IEnumerable`.

I need to programmatically pass which properties make up the 'key' or distinct record and then using LINQ do a `Enumerable.Any()` on the defined properties so it would see if the object already exists in the `IEnumerable`.

Here is my code so far:

```
    // Generic Method
    public void AddItem(TEntity item)
    {
        var entities = GetAllItems().ToList(); // Method gets cached IEnumerable<TEntity>
        
        if(true)  // Generically see if TEntity is already in the list based of defined properties
        {
            entities.Add(item);
        }

    }

    // Same function but non-generic
    private void AddItem(MyObject object)
    {
        var objects = GetAllItems().ToList(); //Method gets cached IEnumerable<MyObject>
        
        if(!objects.Any(a=> a.ID == MyObject.ID ))
        {
            objects.Add(object);
            _cache.AddReplaceCache(objects);
        }
    }
```

**NOTE**: the keys can be any property or properties on the object MyObject

Comment: Seems like this should be a check performed one layer above this.  I'd just let the duplicate key issue fail at the db level since it shouldn't get to the repository.  Then again I'd not be using a generic repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your entities inherit from a common interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can redefine your method like

```
public void AddItem<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : IEntity
{
    // Now you can access entity.ID
}
```

Now, if you don't always want to compare via ID, then you can add a predicate to your method:

```
public void AddItem<TEntity>(TEntity entity, Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
{
    var objects = GetAllItems().ToList();

    // You might need some logic in the predicate to check for null
    if(!objects.Any(a => predicate(a as TEntity))
    {
        objects.Add(entity);
        _cache.AddReplaceCache(objects);
    }

}
```

Then you would use your function as

```
repository.AddItem(entity, e => e.ID == entity.ID && e.OtherProperty == entity.OtherProperty);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly your problem is `TEntity` doesn't have property `ID`. So make your entities to inherit common interface which have for example the ID column.

```
public interface IObject
{
    int ID {get; set;}

    //define all other properties which are shared between your Entities.
}
public class MyObject : IObject
{
    public int ID {get; set;}

    //other properties.
}

public void AddItem(TEntity item): where TEntity:IObject
{
    var entities = GetAllItems().ToList(); //Method gets cached IEnumerable<TEntity>

    if(!objects.Any(a=> a.ID == item.ID ))//Generically see if TEntity is already in the list based of defined properties
    {
        entities.Add(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: As I understand it, each entity can have a composite key made up of multiple fields, and those fields would be passed in and used to check for duplicates.

Comment: @stephen.vakil he is talking about some "key", but I just re write his code to work with generics. If he has keys which are made from multiple fields he need to define them in the interface and after that fetch the data. The process should be the same